# Implementation of Pagination using flask_paginate (pymongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I want to implement flask pagination using flask_paginate. I am using MongoDB

I have made this "home" route to implement this. But it's not working.

This is my home route code

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
if current_user.is_authenticated:
    search = False
    q = request.args.get('q')
    if q:
        search = True

    page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=1)

    posts=mongo.db.articles
    #allpost=posts.find().limit(5)
    it=current_user.user_json['interest']
    allpost=posts.find( {'NewsType': it } )
    pagination = Pagination(page=page,per_page=5 ,total=allpost.count(), search=search, record_name='allpost')

    #flash(session['email'])        
    return render_template('index.html', posts=allpost,pagination=pagination)
else:
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
    #return render_template('login.html', title='Login',form=LoginForm())        

{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for post in posts %}
    <article class="media content-section">
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
         <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.email }}</a>
         <small class="text-muted">{{ post.Date }}</small>
        </div>
        <h2><a class="article-title" href="{{url_for('post',post_id=post._id)}}">{{ post.Heading }}</a></h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.NewsType }}</p>
      </div>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
{{ pagination.links }}
```

And this is the index.html file i am using

I want 5 articles per page. 
Can somebody please tell me why this code not working because I can go next page but it shows all articles instead of 5

Comment: Did you try `allpost = posts.find( {'NewsType': it } ).skip((page - 1) * per_page).limit(per_page)`?

Comment: Not i did not try this 
Let me try this first

Comment: Its working, But how to align these Links in view in Horizontal because it gets Vertical (using css)

Comment: Now that I don’t know, that would be a different question altogether

Comment: Okay Thanks Alot :) For the help